# 302 redirect loop... with a twist

Tags: linux, apache, curl, centos

I have this situation that utterly baffles me:

#### The setup

a newly setup server (centos 7, apache, mysql, nothing fancy) that hosts a simple php app that I need to interact with from my main app on another server. This service is setup to run on service-name.domain.tld while the main app is on domain.tld (just mentioning in case it make any difference).

### The problem

For some reason when I try to access the service app from the main server I get an endless loop of 302 redirects.

If I do a `curl -D - http://service-name.domain.tld` from the main server I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 12:30:26 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://service-name.domain.tld
Content-Length: 218
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://email-blasts.upgradesale.co">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

If I do the same command from my computer, the result is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 12:31:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.6.24
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 30
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Welcome.
```

As it should be. Same happens for any request I make (even static files). Also I should specify same situation happens for `wget` and `get_file_contents` in php

I'm really lost right now, not knowing where to go from here. So any kind of direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: make curl copy your web browser's request to-the-letter, fake the user agent string, make sure its using connection: keep-alive, cache-control, Accept "text/html,applicatiion/xhtml"~, "accept-language", all that shit, then you should get the same result. now go slowly backwards, removing the fake user agent and stuff, eventually you will find that 1 thing that makes the response differ.. hopefully

Comment: got a live url we can test on? :P